# Interpretation of a probability that does not normalize to one in stat mech?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, probability, statistics

I am trying to understand the meaning of the "n-particle distribution function" as defined by the three references below([1][2][3]), primarily those by Claudio Zannoni.

Setup: For a system with N classical cylindrical particles each with a location described by $ \textbf{r} _i = \langle r_{i,x},r_{i,y}, r_{i,z} \rangle $ and an orientation described by $ \Omega_i = (\alpha, \beta) $ with $\alpha$ being the polar angle and $\beta$ the azimuthal, the generalized coordinates for the ith particle are given as $\textbf{X}_i = (\textbf{r}_i,\Omega_i)$, and the overall configuration of the N particle system is described by $ \widetilde{\textbf{X}} = (\textbf{X}_1,\textbf{X}_2, ... \textbf{X}_N)$.

It is written that the probability density, $P(\textbf{X})$, describes the probability for any molecule to be found at $\textbf{X}$ and possesses units that are inverse to that of  $\textbf{X}$. Additionally, instead of defining $P(\textbf{X})$ in the usual way as the integral of the Boltzmann factors over the partition function, it is described in terms of the delta function, which is written as $P(\textbf{X}) = \langle \delta (\textbf{X} - \textbf{X}')\rangle_{\textbf{X}'} $ which I interpret to be the number of particles with $\textbf{X} = \textbf{X}'$ divided by the total number of particles. Ok, more or less so far so good.

Zannoni then introduces the "n-particle-distribution function," $P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}}) $,  Which he interprets as the probability of finding n particles out of the total N in the range $\textbf{X}_1 + d\textbf{X}_1,\textbf{X}_2 + d\textbf{X}_2, ... ,\textbf{X}_n + d\textbf{X}_n  $. The form is then given as

$$P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}}) = _{n}P_{r} \frac{\int e^{-\beta U(\widetilde{\textbf{X}})} d\textbf{X}_{n+1}d\textbf{X}_{n+2} ...  d\textbf{X}_{N} } {Z_N}$$

$$P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}}) = \frac{N!}{(N-n)!} \frac{\int e^{-\beta U(\widetilde{\textbf{X}})} d\textbf{X}_{n+1}d\textbf{X}_{n+2} ...  d\textbf{X}_{N} } {Z_N}$$

The partition function is described in the usual way for the canonical ensemble $Z_N = \int e^{-\beta U(\widetilde{\textbf{X}})} d\textbf{X}_{1}d\textbf{X}_{2} ...  d\textbf{X}_{N} $.

However, **my issue arises when he notes that the n-particle distribution function is  not normalized to one, but rather to the number of 'n-plets' or $_N P _n$ permutations available to the system.** Thus, how can it be interpreted as the **probability** of finding n particles out of the total N in the desired range?

I understand that it must normalize to $_N P _n$ given how it is defined. And, I think I understand the terms in the expression for $P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$, with $ \frac{\int e^{-\beta U(\widetilde{\textbf{X}})} d\textbf{X}_{n+1}d\textbf{X}_{n+2} ...  d\textbf{X}_{N} } {Z_N}$ simply being the marginalized joint probability function for the system where now instead of considering the full joint probability for all particles, $P( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$, we are considering the joint marginal probability distribution for only the n particles of interest i.e. now it is $P( (\textbf{X}_1,\textbf{X}_2, ... , \textbf{X}_n))$ vs $P( (\textbf{X}_1,\textbf{X}_2, ... , \textbf{X}_n, ...,\textbf{X}_N)) $. To me, this marginal joint probability should have the interpretation which he assigns to $P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$, that is  "the probability of finding n particles in the range $\textbf{X}_1 + d\textbf{X}_1,\textbf{X}_2 + d\textbf{X}_2, ... ,\textbf{X}_n + d\textbf{X}_n  $"

For the remaining leading term in $P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$, I can kind of rationalize it because any of the n particles can be at the coordinates of interest for $P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$, we multiply by the permutation formula. But how can this still be interpreted as a probability?

It seems to me that $P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$ is more like an expected value, like it should be the expected value of the number of particles in a given coordinate hyper volume, but it doesn't quite fit the expected value formula: $E(X) = \int xf(x) dx$, so this is not quite it either.

**Therefore, what is the correct interpretation of this n-particle distribution function?** Can you put it in more abstract probabilistic terms, such as an expected value, an average value of a joint pdf or something like that?

Many thanks in advance.

[1] - https://borisv.lk.net/matsc597c-1997/systems/Lecture3/node2.html

[2] - https://claudiozannoni.it/cambridge77_opdf.pdf equation (2) and (3).

[3] - Claudio Zannoni, "Liquid Crystals and Their Computer Simulations," Cambridge University Press, 2022. Chapter 3, page 110.
https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108539630.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/695049/probability-more-than-1-when-integrating-the-electron-density-in-density-functio)

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thank you for the reference, this highly related, but unfortunately there the explanation still is not illuminating for me. The discussion under equation 1.18 through 1.22 in the reference linked in the answer is essentially the same logic as repeated by Zannoni.

Comment: I don't understand. It is exactly the same problem, and it is the answer to your question. Do you understand that the probability that a dice shows ($1$ or $2$) OR $2,3,4,5,6$ does not add to one? Or, more generally: $p(A\cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A\cap B)$

Comment: Thank you for the discussion! The inclusion-exclusion principle did come to mind, but I had a hard time seeing how it applies here. In this case it would be $P(\text{particle at }X) = P(X_1 = X) + P(X_2=X) ... P(X_N = X) - P(X_1=X and X_2=X) ... \text{ and so on}$. For $P^{(1)}(X) = N P(X)$ you can get that if you use the inclusion exclusion principle and assume the probability that any two particles are in the same place is zero. But, mathematically why is that the case? There is nothing in the expression for P(X) that makes it such that $P(X_1=X and X_2=X) = 0$ to me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long talk with a mathematician friend has cleared things up.

First things first, $P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$ is simply not a probability distribution. A probability must indeed by normalized to one.

Then, what is it?

Imagine I gathered all the $_NP_n$ permutations of the $N$ particles and I wanted to check how many of these *permutations* fall in the range $\textbf{X}_1 + d\textbf{X}_1,\textbf{X}_2 + d\textbf{X}_2, ... ,\textbf{X}_n + d\textbf{X}_n  $. Let $M$ be the number of permutations that ''succeed" by falling within the desired range. Then we have

$$E[M] = \sum_{i=0}^{_NP_n}P(M=i)*i $$
Here, i is the number of permutations within the portion of phase space. We sum over the  possible number of sets that can be in the desired portion of phase space from 0 to $_NP_n$. Now, whether or not each permutation is in the desired area can be thought of as a Bernoulli trial. Thus, the probability of having i successes can be modelled with a Binomial distribution:

$$E[M] = \sum_{i=0}^{_NP_n} \frac{_NP_n !}{i!(_NP_n - i)!}(\widetilde{P_i})^i (1-\widetilde{P_i})^{_NP_n - i}  * i $$

where $\widetilde{P_i}$ is the probability for any given permutation to succeed by being in the desired range. I.e. it is the marginal probability of success for n out the N particles to be at the desired location this is the marginal probability discussed in the question above. Note that in general this is not the same for every permutation, but we have assumed that it is. This implies that the system is symmetric with respect to interchange of particles. Next we do some algebraic manipulation of this expression, pulling out terms and noting the i=0 term contributes 0 to our sum:
$$E[M] = _NP_n \widetilde{P_i}  \sum_{i=1}^{_NP_n} \frac{(_NP_n-1)!}{(i-1)!(_NP_n - i)!}(\widetilde{P_i})^{i-1} (1-\widetilde{P_i})^{_NP_n - i}  * i $$
let $j = i-1$:
$$E[M] = _NP_n \widetilde{P_j}  \sum_{j=0}^{_NP_n-1} \frac{(_NP_n-1)!}{j!(_NP_n - 1-j)!}(\widetilde{P_j})^{j} (1-\widetilde{P_j})^{_NP_n -1-j }  * j $$
Then we use the binomial theorem:
$$E[M] = _NP_n \widetilde{P_j}  (\widetilde{P_j} + (1-\widetilde{P_j})^{_NP_n-1} $$
and finally we arrive at:
$$E[M] = _NP_n \widetilde{P_j} = _NP_n \frac{\int e^{-\beta U(\widetilde{\textbf{X}})} d\textbf{X}_{n+1}d\textbf{X}_{n+2} ...  d\textbf{X}_{N} } {Z_N} = P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})   $$

Thus $P^{(n)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$ is the expected number of permutations that fall within the specified range. The first one of these $P^{(1)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$ is the *Number density* of particles, so if you want to know the real expected value of the number of particles in a given region, you can integrate $P^{(1)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$ over that region. $P^{(1)}( \widetilde{\textbf{X}})$  can be thought of as having units of $\frac{[Number][Probability]}{[ \widetilde{\textbf{X}}]}$

The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function has the best derivation I have found so far, although it still confuses a bit expected value vs. probability.